# How do I add a lot of contenttype aliases to a new Content Organizer Rule using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, content-organizer-rule

**NOTE! This post is about adding MANY, BUT NOT ALL content types to your rule. If you simply need to create a rule for ALL content types, go straight to the bottom of this post.**

I'm creating a Powershell script to automatically add a lot of content organizer rules to a Sharepoint site.

The site has loads of content types, and each rule is valid for all the content types. Therefore I want to add all content types to each rule's Content Type Aliases property (the "RoutingAliases" field in the Content Organizer Rules list).

Here is the code to create a content organizer rule:

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint/docs"
$Rule = New-Object Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouterRule($Web)
$Rule.Name = "Test rule"
$Rule.ConditionsString = "<Conditions></Conditions>"
$Rule.ContentTypeString = "General document"
$Rule.Priority = "5"
$Rule.RouteToExternalLocation = $false
$Rule.TargetPath = "/docs/department"
$Rule.Enabled = $true

$Aliases = "Letter/Letter from CEO/Letter from CFO"
$Rule.Aliases = $Aliases

$Rule.Update()
```

The code above only works as long as $Aliases is less than 255 characters long.

**Update**

I haven't found any way to get around the 255 character limit to the RoutingAliases field.

The only solution I have found is to create several rules. I have a check in my script, so when I reach 255 characters I create a new rule. See example below:

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint/docs"
$Rule = New-Object `
    Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouterRule($Web)
$Rule.ConditionsString = `
    "<Conditions></Conditions>"
$Rule.ContentTypeString = "General document"
$Rule.Priority = "5"
$Rule.RouteToExternalLocation = $false
$Rule.TargetPath = "/docs/departmentx"
$Rule.Enabled = $true

$Aliases = ""
$RuleNumber = 1
$Rule.Name = "My rule " + $RuleNumber

# Add all contenttypes to the new rule

# NB! $Rule.Aliases can only be up to 255 characters long,
# when this limit is reached we have to make a new rule

# Note that I have all my content types stored in an XML file,
# but you might as well get this from Sharepoint itself

$ContentTypes = [xml] (Get-Content $ContentTypesConfigFile)
$ContentTypes.config.contenttypes.contenttype | 
    ForEach-Object {

    if(($Aliases.Length + $_.Name.Length) -lt 250)
    {
        # Keep adding document types until we reach the limit
        if($Aliases.Length -gt 0) 
        {
            $Aliases += "/"
        }
        $Aliases += $_.Name
    }
    else
    {
        # Reached limit, create rule, start working on next rule
        $Rule.Aliases = $Aliases
        $Rule.Update()
        Write-Host "Rule created:" $Rule.Name
        $RuleNumber++
        $Rule.Name = $RuleName + " " + $RuleNumber
        $Aliases = $_.Name
    }
}
# Save final rule
$Rule.Aliases = $Aliases
$Rule.Update()
```

This script will create "Rule 1", "Rule 2", etc, untill all document types are added as aliases to a rule.

**Another update**

The script above is necessary if you need to add many, but not all content types to your rule. However, if you want to create a rule for ALL content types, simply set

```
$Rule.Aliases = "*"
```

This rule will catch all content types.

Comment: It's not because there are 12, it's the maximum text length of the field in characters.

Comment: $Rule.Aliases can be max 255 characters long. I updated the text above to reflect this. Thanks, @HughWood

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding them one at a time?  For instance:

```
$Aliases = @( "Letter", "Letter from CEO", "Letter from CFO" )  # add more aliases here as needed

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Aliases.Length; $i++)
{
    $Rule.Aliases += $Aliases[$i]
    if ($i -lt $Aliases.Length - 1) { $Rule.Aliases += "/" }
}
```

You might need an update in there as well.

That might avoid reaching some text limit as implied by Hugh Wood.

Comment: This didn't work, I'm afraid. I got the same error as when I ran my own code.

I tried putting a $Rule.Update() in the loop as well, but a new rule was created every time I called Update().

Comment: @DylanCristy: Is there a way to create `content organizer rule` using csom powershell for SharePoint 2013 Online?

Comment: @AsadRefai I am not familiar with the Powershell cmdlets available for SP Online, so I couldn't really say, sorry.

Comment: @DylanCristy : So is it possible using c# csom?

Comment: @AsadRefai, again, not really sure, sorry.

Comment: @DylanCristy : I have finished the quest see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150099/create-content-organizer-rule-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom-code