# How to create Content Organizer rules through powershell in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: powershell, content

I have a bunch of doc libraries. I need to create content organizer rules for these 2000 libraries through powershell? Any help will be appreciated. I also have to fill the condition string.

Comment: Will you be running this `PowerShell` script on the server which has SharePoint?

Comment: Yes the server has sharepoint 2010 installed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `PowerShell` script to create a content organizer rule. It uses `Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouterRule`

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]$site = Get-SPSite http://www.mycompany.com
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$web = Get-SPWeb http://www.mycompany.com
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType]$ct = $site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["MyContentType"]
[Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouterRule]$rule = New-Object Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouterRule($web)

$rule.Aliases = $ct.Name
$rule.ConditionsString = "<conditions></conditions>"
$rule.CustomRouter = ""
$rule.Name = $ct.Name
$rule.Description = "Routes '" + $ct.Name + "' documents to it's own library"
$rule.ContentTypeString = $ct.Name
$rule.RouteToExternalLocation = $false
$rule.Priority = "5"
$rule.TargetPath = $web.Lists["MyLibrary"].RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
$rule.Enabled = $true
$rule.Update()
```

Comment: I have the list of Doc libraries in a csv file for each of them i need to create a seperate org rule.how do i accomodate this?

Comment: Are those doc libraries in your `Record Centre` site?

Comment: Ideal situation is: You have some `Document libraries` in your record centre site. And `Content Organizer rule` is the one which redirects the received documents from other site collections to the destination libraries based on `Content Types`. So My advice is you do not create rule for Doc Lib but for Content Types.

Comment: yes... my url is something like this : http://myurl/rec/subsite/"the 2000 library names 1 by 1"/subfolder/subfolder. This is where the documents should route. That means i need to create 2000 diff org rules for each of these libraries

Comment: i want the library names to be dynamic from a csv as i want this powershell to run 2000 times for the 2000 diff library names

Comment: Yes then you create a function out of the supplied code which accepts parameters from csv.

Comment: Ive used your scrip and it works, but I notice that once I hit over 150 rules, the creation process slows down...considerably. I have over 600 rules to apply, Ive tried IISRESETs rebooting all servers, added a $site.dispose() nothing seemed to help the speeds. It will take 5mins 10 secs per rule when I had a empty site it created them in less than 10-15 seconds.

Comment: @JWJ : See if CSOM script works for you. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150099/create-content-organizer-rule-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom-code